# Android. Создать папку приложения на usb устройстве

Tags: android, usb, android-permissions

У меня есть MiBox на android 6. К нему подключается usb устройство как /storage/1A43-C170. Файлы на нем вижу, могу воспроизвести с него видео.
Проблема с созданием/редактированием файлов.
Прекрасно написали об этом [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40068984/universal-way-to-write-to-external-sd-card-on-android/40201333#40201333)

Меня интересует пункт:

> Use your app specific path /storage/extSdCard/Android/data/com.myapp.example/files.

Этот вариант мне более чем подходит.
Мой вопрос в том, как создать папку приложения на флешке?

Многие приложения создают свои папки на моей флешке.

К примеру, Total Commander. В нем я могу создать файл в его папке 
/storage/1A43-C170/Android/data/com.ghisler.android.TotalCommander/files/, но в других папках на usb я не могу создавать файлы через него. Т.е. приложение имеет доступ только к своей папке. Хочу так же для своего приложения.

Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() возвращает мне /storage/emulated/0.
Разрешения для моего приложения прописаны.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

getExternalFilesDirs create app directory.

```
File[] files = context.getExternalFilesDirs(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
for (File file : files) {
    Log.d("STORAGEEEEE", file.getAbsolutePath());
}
```